# "Missing type in composite literal" error

Tags: go

I am getting the following error, while executing this Go program. not sure what I am missing.

```
.\m.go:28: missing type in composite literal
.\m.go:28: too few values in struct initializer
```

<kbd>[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SseWnsX3jN)</kbd>

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type LI struct {
    Id int `json:"id"`
}

type TP struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

type LTI struct {
    Leads  []LI `json:"leads"`
    Tokens []TP `json:"tokens,omitempty"`
}

type RCR struct {
    Input LTI `json:"input"`
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    leadIdInput := LI{Id: 55213}
    leadTokensInput := LTI{{[]LI{leadIdInput}, nil}}
    rCR := RCR{Input: leadTokensInput}
    fmt.Println("rCR is '%+v'", rCR.Input.Leads[0])
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
LTI{Leads: []LI{leadIdInput}}
```

and

```
fmt.Printf("rCR is '%+v' \n", rCR.Input.Leads[0])
```

Try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TADgKGFrqv):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type LI struct {
    Id int `json:"id"`
}

type TP struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

type LTI struct {
    Leads  []LI `json:"leads"`
    Tokens []TP `json:"tokens,omitempty"`
}

type RCR struct {
    Input LTI `json:"input"`
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    leadIdInput := LI{Id: 55213}
    leadTokensInput := LTI{Leads: []LI{leadIdInput}}
    rCR := RCR{Input: leadTokensInput}
    fmt.Printf("rCR is '%+v' \n", rCR.Input.Leads[0])
}
```

output:

```
Hello, playground
rCR is '{Id:55213}'
```

Comment: @skm  I hope this helps.